# Why does UILongPressGestureRecognizer return twice

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

The following code seems to print the values twice even though I hold down for 2 seconds.

No matter what duration I change to it always seems to execute twice, does anyone know why this might be?

```
func action(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer){
    var touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.myMap);
    var newCo = myMap.convertPoint(touchPoint, toCoordinateFromView: self.myMap);
    var annotation = MKPointAnnotation();
    annotation.coordinate = newCo;
    var loc = CLLocation(latitude: newCo.latitude, longitude: newCo.longitude);
            CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(loc, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in
        let pm:CLPlacemark = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark;

        var address = pm.locality + " ," + pm.postalCode + " ," + pm.administrativeArea + " ," + pm.country;
        annotation.title = address;
        self.myMap.addAnnotation(annotation);
        println(address);
        println("\(newCo.latitude)");
        println("\(newCo.longitude)");
        //places.append(["name:":address, "lat": "\(newCo.latitude)", "lon":"\(newCo.longitude)"]);
    })


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the state property of the UIGestureRecognizer, you're probably getting both begin and end.

```
enum UIGestureRecognizerState : Int {
    case Possible
    case Began
    case Changed
    case Ended
    case Cancelled
    case Failed
}
```

Comment: so i would want to wrap my code in a if(gesture state.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began){do-stuff?}

Comment: Yes, either on the begin or end, depends on how you want the user to interact with it. That is to say, use begin if you want to print the location once the long press duration has been triggered, or use end when the user releases from the press.

Answer (score 0):

```
func action(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Gesture Recognized")

    if gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
        let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.map)
        let newCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D = self.map.convertPoint(touchPoint, toCoordinateFromView: self.map)
        print(newCoordinate)
        listNewCoordinates.append(newCoordinate)
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate.longitude = newCoordinate.longitude
        annotation.coordinate.latitude = newCoordinate.latitude

        self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }

}
```

Comment: The "if gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended" section permits the code within the conditional to be ran only why the UIGestureRecognizer has registered that the gesture is over.

The function runs for two states, it runs when the gesture begins and it runs when the gesture ends. By using the if-statement you can force it to only run once.